# How to just build/update a single Docker image instead of all services after docker-compose up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file with a few services declared within.

When I type `docker-compose up` they all start.

Now, I wish to fix just one of them. I usually then `docker-compose down` which stops **all** of them. Instead, I'm hoping to just pull down the one service I need to fix, fix it (build/compile/etc) and then start up that single Docker image.

So is there a way I can do this instead of doing:

- `docker-compose down` (**all** services stop)
- build/compile code in the service I wish to update
- `docker-compose up --build`  (**all** services compile/build/ ... )

Comment: Can you try: `docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps service-name`

Answer (score 1):

You re-build the images and do a `docker-compose up`, which will automatically detect the the image is updated and recreate the service. Down side of building an images while the container from that image is running is that it will leave a none image, since docker won't delete image. You could overcome by removing the container from that image before hand by either one of these commands.

```
docker rm -vf <container-name>
docker rm -vr <container-id>
```

If that is inconvenient for you could delete the `none` images afterwards by,

```
docker rmi <image-id>
```

Also, if you have multiple `none` images hanging, you could remove all by,

```
docker images -q --filter "dangling=true" | xargs docker rmi -f
```

Answer (score 1):

We normally go with:

```
docker-compose stop servicename
docker-compose rm servicename
```

and then:

```
docker-compose up -d servicename
```